# R: create inefficient loop in purpose to avoid bothering other server users

Tags: r, loops, parallel-processing

I have to process a dataset in my server, and using different parameters.

This a dummy example of what I'm doing

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
p_load(dplyr,DBI)

mtcars_experiments = dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "mtcars_experiments.sqlite")

for(a in -1:1) {
  for(b in -1:1) {
    for(c in -1:1) {
      mtcars_experiment = mtcars %>% 
        mutate(my_col = mpg^a + cyl^b + disp^c)

      dbWriteTable(mtcars_experiments, paste("mtcars_experiment",a,b,c, sep = "_"), mtcars_experiment)
    }
  }
}
```

I know that for loops sometimes are inefficient but in my case I don't want to compute this at maximum speed.

I'm trying to find a way that is not so slow but also not so fast, because if I use too much resources with parallelization other users of the server will have problems running their own code.

What can I do in this case? How can I do a bounded parallelization or alike?

Thanks !

Comment: I think you could start R from command line with appropriate `--max-mem-size`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. Why not just having the fastest possible computation so that it quickly leaves ressource for others?

Comment: @d.b I'd wish but I have no permissions to do that

Comment: @F.Privé doing that is not allowed because there are processes running actually and interfering with that would be rude

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1) Add `Sys.sleep(1)` after every iteration.  This consumes no resources, and does nothing 1 second after every iteration.

2) Lower the priority of the process.  In ubuntu, you can do this by `renice 20 PROCESS_ID` (20 is the lowest priority).

Comment: @pachamaltese did you know you can close this question by accepting an answer? See the check mark to the left of each answer. You can also change the accepted answer in the future if a better one comes along.

Answer (score 2):

I personally try to avoid multiple loops (*did you know that every time you run more than two loops, Donald Knuth kills a puppy?*). I prefer objects like `d` (it contains all combinations of specified vectors). I run over `d` with `mcapply` and you can specify number of cores, cleanup there. And I usually know how many cores I have on HPCC.

```
library(parallel)

A <- 1:3
B <- 4:6
C <- 7:9
nCore <- 2

dummyFunction <- function(A, B, C) {
    mtcars$mpg ^ A - mtcars$cyl * B + mtcars$disp / C
}

d <- expand.grid(A, B, C)
colnames(d) <- c("A", "B", "C")

mclapply(1:nrow(d), 
         function(i) dummyFunction(d[i, ]$A, d[i, ]$B, d[i, ]$C),
         mc.cores = nCore)
```

This is far from a good answer, but it's what I use. Looking forward for answers from more experienced R users.